# How can I use two Clearcase views simultaneously?

Tags: maven, clearcase

I am running code review tools on a large application. The code is all held in a ClearCase team view, but information on the Maven build is held in another. The developers get a view which includes the code and the Maven build repository, but that is not possible for test teams here. I have a view which lets me see the code and another view which gives me access to the Maven repository.

My problem is I can't seem to find a way to have both views active at once.

To run my test tools I use `cleartool setview -exec "test scripts etc" mycodeview`

Is there a way to run my review tools while also having access to mymavenview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm that for dynamic view, you cannot use `cleartool setview` for several views.

`setview` is only a way to mount the `vobs` directory within your dynamic view to `/vobs`.

I would rather use snapshot views, update their content in a custom path, and through symlink (not managed by ClearCase), make sure I see the relevant content of one view from the other.

Notes:

- a [cleartool symlinks](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21146295) isn't useful here, since one view don't reflect the full content you need.
- dynamic views could be used, but I find them much slower in those case that snapshot views.

Comment: Ahh - I think I understand @VonC. Do you mean to use one view eg mymavenview, copy the data from the view to somewhere local then setview to the codeview and replace references for the maven info with links that point to my local repository?

Comment: @Rory: copy? if you use snapshot views, you don't have to copy, just to add the right links between the views. If you use dynamics views, then you don't need to copy either: you can link to the second view using its MVFS path: `/view/mySecondView/vobs/...`

Comment: I don't really understand that, but it works. Wondering whether the use of cleartool is at all necessary here as it looks like I can do everything I need using /view/view1/vobs/... and /view/view2/vobs/... If both views are actually permanently mounted under the /views/ directory I am baffled as to how clearcase references work (SVN was so much simpler :-)

Comment: @Rory: `/view` is the unique mount point for *all* dynamic views. `/vobs` is just an alias for *one* view to be set, in order to avoid `/view/myView`

Comment: @Rory, @VonC, `/view/<view name>` may not always be mounted. To mount it either someone should have used the view recently in the machine you are working on, or else use the command `cleartool startview <view name>`. More details: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_startview.htm